# Redis newbie - equivalent approach to mysql table

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis and was hoping for a "best practice" solution to implementing the equivalent of a "users" table in a mysql database, for handling users in a web app.

Would I create a users SET in Redis? Or a users database with a SET for each user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My standard setup for users is a serialized object in a standard key u:*userid* - this object gets retrieved on each request, and there is never any need to access only one of the properties.

You could also use a hash rather than json for the user properties, but my setup includes everything getting used as strongly typed objects and redis running on a different server from the client, so using json makes it easier to use generic deserialization and minimizes any latency issues.

In addition to the user object itself, you will need an index for any fields you need to use to find a user - for example to allow a user to log in with email address you will need a key e:*email* => *userid*. A hash will also work here - the important thing is that you need something that is O(1) to get from an email to a user object.

Sometimes parts of the user data should have their own keys - for example a followers list is a perfect match to a redis set, so is best stored in that form.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you'd want to do with the Users within your application.  Another option would be to have each user be it's own hash, where they keys are properties (fields) for each user (firstName, lastName, etc).  You could use a key that you increment as the ID generator for inserting, and potentially another set that you use to hold all of the user IDs.